# In a parallel code in python, a worker process that completes a task later than another worker acquires a lock first? What could cause this behaviour?

Tags: python, debugging, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am new to parallel programming.

My code looks like following

```
for future in as_completed(futures):
    with task_lock:
        #do something
```

I have following log generated from my code.

> 2023-09-21 21:43:49,133 - Worker-1 completed calculation
>
> 2023-09-21 21:50:06,045 - Worker-2 completed calculation
>
> 2023-09-21 21:50:06,141 - Worker-2 entered task lock
>
> 2023-09-21 21:50:06,605 - Worker-1 entered task lock

At 21:43:49 worker 1 finishes but does not enter the task lock. At 21:50:06 worker 2 finishes, and enters the task lock before worker 1. Worker 1 enters the task lock after worker 2.

So, for 7 minutes, worker 1 was waiting for the task lock, but only received it after worker 2 came and accessed the lock.

What could cause this delay? Is it unussual for this kind of delay to happen? I am concerned because for this amount of time, there are less workers working. This appears inefficient.

What could cause this issue? Is there a way to mitigate this? Is this even a bug or a feature?

I must add that the tasks these workers are doing sometimes requires a lot of memory, sometimes also leading to the use of swap memory. Could this explain why there are workers waiting for long for a lock without getting it until more workers are done calculating and hence free up some RAM?